# Connecting xamarin to woocommerce api

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, woocommerce

I'm trying to create my first app that will connect to a woocommerce api.

Has anyone any experience in this or can point me in the direction as to how to create a connection to pull in the product list?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since WooCommerce has a [REST API](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/), it should be fairly simple to connect using a plain HTTP request, or a library like [RestSharp](https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp/).

There is also a [C# client](https://github.com/putuyoga/WoocommerceSharp) for WooCommerce - I don't know if it plays well with Xamarin, you might need to modify it a bit to get it to build.

```
  var api = new WoocommerceApiClient(StoreUrl, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
  var result = await api.Products.Get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but I had faced a similar issue. I had tries [WoocommerceSharp](https://github.com/putuyoga/WoocommerceSharp) with Xamarin Studio 6.1.1 (mac version); I opened the .sln file, added the missing reference to system.net.http and it worked perfectly.

If you want make it work in PCL you have to use PCLCrypto in WoocommerceApiUrlGenerator.cs , here the updated version:

```
namespace SharpCommerce.Web
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using PCLCrypto;

    internal class WoocommerceApiUrlGenerator
    {
        private const string SignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
        private const string ApiV3RootEndpoint = "wc-api/v3/";
        private readonly string baseURI;
        private readonly string consumerKey;
        private readonly string consumerSecret;

        internal WoocommerceApiUrlGenerator(string storeUrl, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret)
        {
            if (
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerKey) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerSecret) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeUrl))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("ConsumerKey, consumerSecret and storeUrl are required");
            }

            this.consumerKey = consumerKey;
            this.consumerSecret = consumerSecret;

            // Need 'http://www.example.com' to be 'http://www.example.com/wc-api/v3/'
            this.baseURI = String.Format("{0}/{1}", storeUrl.TrimEnd('/'), ApiV3RootEndpoint);
        }

        internal string GenerateRequestUrl(HttpMethod httpMethod, string apiEndpoint, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
        {
            parameters = parameters ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();

            parameters["oauth_consumer_key"] = this.consumerKey;

            // oauth_timestamp = number of seconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00 GMT
            // must be a positive integer
            // must be greater than timestamp of previous requests
            parameters["oauth_timestamp"] =
                Math.Round(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            // oauth_nonce = a unique random string for the timestamp.
            // defends against replay attacks
            // service provide will know that this request has never been made before.
            // Just going to hash the time stamp.
            //parameters["oauth_nonce"] = GenerateNonce(parameters["oauth_timestamp"]);

            // Create random 32 char alphnumeric to avoid reused nonces
            parameters["oauth_nonce"] = GenerateNonce();

            // Declare the hashing method your using
            parameters["oauth_signature_method"] = SignatureMethod;

            //parameters["oauth_version"] = "1.0";

            parameters["oauth_signature"] = UpperCaseUrlEncode(this.GenerateSignature(httpMethod, apiEndpoint, parameters));


            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var pair in parameters)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", SafeUpperCaseUrlEncode(pair.Key), SafeUpperCaseUrlEncode(pair.Value));
            }

            // Substring removes first '&'
            var queryString = sb.ToString().Substring(1);

            var url = this.baseURI + apiEndpoint + "?" + queryString;

            return url;
        }

        private string GenerateSignature(HttpMethod httpMethod, string apiEndpoint, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            // 1) Set the HTTP method for the request.
            // set through 'method'


            //2) Set your base request URI – this is the full request URI without query string parameters – and URL encode according to RFC 3986:
            // need 'http://www.example.com/wc-api/v3/orders'
            // to become: 'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwc-api%2Fv1%2Forders'
            var encodedBaseRequestURI = SafeUpperCaseUrlEncode(this.baseURI + apiEndpoint);

            // 3) Collect and normalize your query string parameters
            // percent(%) characters should be double-encoded (e.g. % becomes %25.
            var normalizedParameters = NormalizeParameters(parameters);

            // 4) Sort the parameters in byte-order
            var orderedNormalizedParameters = normalizedParameters.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();

            // 5) Join each parameter with an encoded equals sign (%3D):
            //var joinedOrderedNormalizedParameters = orderedNormalizedParameters.ConvertAll(x => x.Key + "%3D" + x.Value);
            var joinedOrderedNormalizedParameters = new List<string>();
            foreach (var x in orderedNormalizedParameters)
            {
                joinedOrderedNormalizedParameters.Add(x.Key + "%3D" + x.Value);
            }

            // 6) Join each parameter key/value pair with an encoded ampersand (%26):
            var joinedParameterPairs = String.Join("%26", joinedOrderedNormalizedParameters);

            // 7) Form the string to sign by joining the HTTP method, encoded base request URI, and encoded parameter string with an unencoded ampersand symbol (&):
            var stringToSign = string.Format("{0}&{1}&{2}", httpMethod.ToString().ToUpper(), encodedBaseRequestURI, joinedParameterPairs);

            // 8) Generate the signature using the string to key and your consumer secret key
            var preparedStringToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
            var secret = this.consumerSecret + "&";
            var preparedConsumerKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
            var signatureHash = Sha1(preparedConsumerKey, preparedStringToSign);
            var signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureHash);


            return signatureString;
        }



        private static byte[] Sha1(byte[] key, byte[] message)
        {
            var mac = WinRTCrypto.MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HmacSha1);
            //var keyMaterial = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(key, Encoding.UTF8);
            var cryptoKey = mac.CreateKey(key);
            var hash = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Sign(cryptoKey, message);

            return hash;
            //return WinRTCrypto.CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArraymessage);
        }



        private static Dictionary<string, string> NormalizeParameters(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var pair in parameters)
            {
                var upperCaseUrlEncodedKey = SafeUpperCaseUrlEncode(pair.Key);
                var normalizedKey = upperCaseUrlEncodedKey.Replace("%", "%25");

                var upperCaseUrlEncodedValue = SafeUpperCaseUrlEncode(pair.Value);
                var normalizedValue = upperCaseUrlEncodedValue.Replace("%", "%25");

                result.Add(normalizedKey, normalizedValue);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static string SafeUpperCaseUrlEncode(string stringToEncode)
        {
            return UpperCaseUrlEncode(System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(stringToEncode));
        }

        private static string UpperCaseUrlEncode(string stringToEncode)
        {
            var basicUrlEncodedString = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(stringToEncode);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(basicUrlEncodedString)) return String.Empty;

            var upperCaseUrlEncodedString = Regex.Replace(
                basicUrlEncodedString,
                "(%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])",
                c => c.Value.ToUpper());

            return upperCaseUrlEncodedString;
        }

        private static string GenerateNonce()
        {
            const string ValidChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            var random = new Random();

            var nonceString = new StringBuilder();
            for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            {
                nonceString.Append(ValidChars[random.Next(0, ValidChars.Length - 1)]);
            }

            return nonceString.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and in WoocommerceApiDriver.cs you will have to replace

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            }
```

by

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) // must use to avoid Android freezes after repeated calls
    {

        Task<HttpResponseMessage> r = client.GetAsync(url);
        HttpResponseMessage m = r.Result;
        return await m.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Et voila ! ca marche ;)